# Error Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document} appearing on beamer

Tags: beamer

Today I'm having problems with beamer.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\date{\year}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            \begin{block}
                \centering
                \textbf{Título}
            \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But it shows a error message: "Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}", on the line 4.

This error appears when I try to change the theme. When I don't put the `\usetheme{}` it works perfectly.

Someone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\year` is an internal register you want

```
\date{\the\year}
```

To get the typeset number